# jQuery on function doesnt work

Tags: jquery

My html:

```
<div style="top:10px;display:block" class="jPlugin_article_pager">
    <span style="cursor:pointer" class="jPlugin_article_page" data-id="1">1</span>
    <span style="cursor:pointer" class="jPlugin_article_page" data-id="2">2</span>
</div>
```

My jquery

```
  $('.jPlugin_article_pager').on('click','.jPlugin_article_page',function(event){
            alert('works');
                console.log($(this).attr('data-id') + ' was pressed. Details:  Event target : '+ event.target+ '. Type:' + event.type );
});
```

I just want the alert to be triggered when you click teh jPlugin_article_page element.
  Note.  jPlugin_article_pager is generated dynamically and so jPlugin_article_page. I dont need to use document ready function cause my code is near the closing body tag..

I would like to know what is wrong..thanks

UPDATE:

weirdly enough.. i dont know what i changed but this works:

```
    $('.jPlugin_article_pager').on('click','.jPlugin_article_page',function(event){
                 alert($(this).attr('data-id'));
                console.log($(this).attr('data-id') + ' was pressed. Details:  Event target : '+ event.target+ '. Type:' + event.type );
            });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as `.jPlugin_article_pager` is created dynamically you should delegate the event from another static parent like body tag, try this:

```
$('body').on('click', '.jPlugin_article_page', function(event){
    alert('works');
    console.log($(this).attr('data-id') + ' was pressed. Details:  Event target : '+ event.target+ '. Type:' + event.type );
});
```

Comment: I tried to refrain from using body. could i bind, pager to body and then bind pager to page?

Comment: @DmitryMakovetskiyd yes, you can choose another element which is static parent of the dynamically generated element.,

Answer (score 2):

The event is only bound to something that is actually there when the code is called. You seem to be sure you don't need the document ready function, sure, but is the actual DOM element on the screen when you get to this code?

You say it is generated dynamically, so my guess it that it isn't. And you can't bind functions to objects that are not there. Call this code AFTER you have dynamically added the object, for instance in the same function that actually creates the object.

Comment: I agree with this, seeing as how it works here: http://jsfiddle.net/HillbillyDeveloper/tQUva/, which has everything already generated.

Comment: dammit.. so i have to add it in document ready..even though the code is near the body closing tag

Comment: I'm not really sure what your beef is with document.ready? Is there a problem? Anyway, be aware that if the trigger of the dynamically adding is for instance a user-action, the DOM-element isn't even ready on document-ready. Without seeing all the code is hard to say, but you might just append this code to the code that generates the elements.